# ASP.NET Image Upload Parameter Not Valid. Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, upload, uploadify

Im just trying to save a file to disk using a posted stream from jquery uploadify

I'm also getting Parameter not valid.

On adding to the error message so i can tell where it blew up in production im seeing it blow up on:

```
   var postedBitmap = new Bitmap(postedFileStream)
```

any help would be most appreciated

```
public string SaveImageFile(Stream postedFileStream, string fileDirectory, string fileName, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{
    string result = "";
    string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, fileName);
    string exhelp = "";

    if (!File.Exists(fullFilePath))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var postedBitmap = new Bitmap(postedFileStream))
            {
                exhelp += "got past bmp creation" + fullFilePath;

                using (var imageToSave = ImageHandler.ResizeImage(postedBitmap, imageWidth, imageHeight))
                {
                    exhelp += "got past resize";

                    if (!Directory.Exists(fileDirectory))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDirectory);
                    }

                    result = "Success";
                    postedBitmap.Dispose();
                    imageToSave.Save(fullFilePath, GetImageFormatForFile(fileName));
                }

                exhelp += "got past save";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = "Save Image File Failed " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
            Global.SendExceptionEmail("Save Image File Failed " + exhelp, ex);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If it produced an exception on that call with the message "parameter not valid", then it would seem that `postedFileStream` is not valid.  Verify that the call to SaveImageFile is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image converter to load from byte array:

```
ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
Image image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(byteArray) as Image;
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1109959.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems your stream type is not valid for Bitmap object, try to copy stream to MemoryStream, and give MemoryStream as a parameter of Bitmap

and remove second dispose as @Aliostad mentoined

something like this

```
public string SaveImageFile(Stream postedFileStream, string fileDirectory, string fileName, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
        {
            string result = "";
            string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, fileName);
            string exhelp = "";
            if (!File.Exists(fullFilePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                       postedFileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                       memoryStream.Position = 0;
                       using (var postedBitmap = new Bitmap(memoryStream))
                       {
                         .........
                        }

                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)

                {

                    result = "Save Image File Failed " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;

                    Global.SendExceptionEmail("Save Image File Failed " + exhelp, ex);

                }

            }



            return result;

        }
```